# @font-face: удачный опыт использования?

Tags: css

У кого был удачный опыт использования, помогите.

Всяко разно пробовал. Максимум чего добился это работы шрифта в Хроме и ФФ. Опера и ИЕ пока отказываются видеть нестандартный шрифт. CSS такой:

```
/* только для Internet Explorer */
@font-face {
   font-family: etelkatext;
   src: url('EtelkaText.eot');
}

/* далее для всех остальных браузеров */
@font-face {
  font-family: etelkatext;
  src: url('EtelkaText.otf');
}

body
{font-family:etelkatext;}
```

Comment: [http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face][1]
[1]:http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face

Answer (score 1):

А я бы предложил заюзать [гугл шрифты](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/webfonts/), там и [примерчики](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html#Quick_Start) есть. И, кстати, их даже можно сделать автономными.

Сам использую RaphaelJS ([print](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.print)) в с вязке с [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/).

**UPD.**
Может так попробовать:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
/* только для Internet Explorer */
@font-face {
   font-family: etelkatext;
   src: url('EtelkaText.eot');
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
/* далее для всех остальных браузеров */
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: etelkatext;
  src: url('EtelkaText.otf');
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/* только для Internet Explorer */
@font-face { 
  font-family: EtelkaText; 
  src: local("EtelkaText"), 
  url(path-to/EtelkaText.eot); 
}

/* далее для всех остальных браузеров */
@font-face { 
  font-family: EtelkaText; 
  src: local("EtelkaText"), 
  url(path-to/EtelkaText.ttf); 
}
```

Comment: ни в одном браузере не сработало

Answer (score -1):

```
@font-face {
font-family: "mb";
src:url('fonts/magistralc-bold-webfont.eot?') format('eot'), 
    url('fonts/magistralc-bold-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

Для всех браузеров.

Comment: @font-face {
font-family: 'etelkatext';
src:url('EtelkaText.eot?') format('eot'), 
    url('EtelkaText.ttf')  format('truetype');
}



body
{font-family:'etelkatext';}

Тоже ни в одном не сработало

Comment: а так и не заработает

@font-face { font-family: 'etelkatext'; src:url('EtelkaText.eot?') format('eot'), url('EtelkaText.ttf') format('truetype'); }
*{font-family:'etelkatext';}

Answer (score -1):

По моему без участия JS кроссбраузерности не добиться, [вот](http://depublic.venzdesign.com/blog/typefacejs-ispolzovanie-nestandartnykh-shriftov-na-saite) тут рабочая версия.